# How to clear cache without restarting the browser

Tags: c#, browser-cache

i'm trying to remove cache without restart the browser with asp.net C# code.
this is my code

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("email_address");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

HttpCookie tenantcookie = new HttpCookie("tenant_id");
tenantcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(tenantcookie);

HttpCookie access_token = new HttpCookie("access_token");
access_token.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(access_token);
```

The cache has been deleted, but I have to close my browser and open my browser again to show see if the cache has been delete or not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are not deleting the cache: you are just creating 3 expired  cookies

Comment: Press Crtl + Shift + Del on FF, Chrome and IE ? Is it for test only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337149/how-to-clear-browser-cache-on-browser-back-button-click-in-mvc4

Answer (score 0):

Because of security reasons you can't clear a browser's history using code.

You can delete all files and folders under browsers cache directory,
This is the default cache location for

- mozilla-"C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxx.xxxx"
- chrome="\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache."

It is hidden and you change view from folder option.