# Page still shows after logout when back button is clicked asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

I have seen lot of questions almost similar to this. But, I haven't found an answer that will fix my problem.

I have a logout button and I used Session.Abandon() and Session.Clear() to clear the session. It works fine. But, whenever I hit the back button on browser the page is still showing. But, it's supposed to show the login form because the user already logged out.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
     Session.Clear();
     Session.Abandon();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "LogIn");
}
```

How to fix this?.Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the `Authorize` attribute to check for authorization in your Actions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: @juanreyesv: No, I check it this way: 
          try
            {
                connect = connection.getConnection();
                model = new Models.Entities(connect);
                connect.Open();
                connect.Close();

            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "LogIn");
            } . What should be done instead of doing this?Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set NoCache in `global.asax`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashiwini!..it worked! :) I'm just wondering if there's a downside on using this method?

Comment: The only downside is that it sets nocache on application level. see the reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337149/how-to-clear-browser-cache-on-browser-back-button-click-in-mvc4?rq=1

Comment: It's like running the whole system from the start without relying on the cache which will retrieve the page faster..Is it right?

Comment: "running the whole system from the start without relying on the cache", yes that's correct. However, I don't think this will cause faster loading of page.

Comment: Thank you very much Ashiwini...:) You helped me a lot. :D

Comment: Glad that I could help. :)

Comment: I want to ask again if not relying to cache would slow down its performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to "ServerAndNoCache" to force browser not to cache the page instead server to cache the page so there are no extra load on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread where I got the answer for this
[Prevent Caching in ASP.NET MVC for specific actions using an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute)

My solution (.Net 6 MVC) was the one below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System;

namespace YourSolutionName.Web.Mvc.Controllers.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                    new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                    {
                        NoStore = true,
                        NoCache = true,
                    };

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then adding the [NoCache] to the controllers I wanted.

I choose this because it provided a finer control over where I wanted to disable the caching, but if you would like to do it for the whole solution,
it ca be done with middleware (on Startup.cs)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
            app.UseResponseCaching();
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                    new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                    {
                        NoStore = true,
                        NoCache = true,
                    };

                await next();
            });
```