# Browser back button fails - ONLY IF postback has been performed on previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, back-button

I'll keep this simple. I have two pages:

- List page
- Detail page

Quick info on the list page:

- A grid to show list of items with a "view" hyperlink each pointing to the detail page (e.g. detail.aspx?id=1)
- A number of filters and a search button
- By default the list shows all items without any filtering

Scenario 1 (OK):

- Without any filtering, click on any of the view links
- This will take me to the detail page of the selected item
- Click on the browser back button, the list page is shown (OK)

Scenario 2 (Not OK):

- Do a search filter on the list page, this triggers a postback with filtered items
- Click on one of the view links
- This will take me to the detail page of the selected item
- Click on the browser back button, **ERROR PAGE**!

Error info:

- IE: Webpage has expired
- Chrome: ERR_CACHE_MISS
- Firefox: Document expired

Any idea why scenario 2 fails to bring up the list page? I don't need the filters to be retained when going back, I just need the list page displayed straight away without the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337149/how-to-clear-browser-cache-on-browser-back-button-click-in-mvc4) is a similar discussion.

But what I did was to disable the back button with a line of Javascript to prevent these kind of problems

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.forward();
</script>
```

And I inserted a "Back" or "Return" button into the second page which will be used to go back to the initial page.

I hope this is convenient for you.

Comment: Disabling browser back button is not an option. So I tried adding the three lines of code into Global.asax Application_BeginRequest as suggested in the linked question but it did not help. :-(