# How i can clean cache browser with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, browser-cache

I have **ASP.NET MVC application**.
How I can *clear browser cache*, specifically folders `/Content` and `/Script`,
 using the some method in the controller?

Comment: With headers that will 'instruct' the browser to do so. This has already been answered, though - I'll flag it now....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear browser cache on browser back button click in MVC4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337149/how-to-clear-browser-cache-on-browser-back-button-click-in-mvc4)

Comment: ^ Note - asking specifically about back button - but accepted answer still addresses your question. There may be more complexities with your case (i.e. bundling) - but you haven't stated any yet.